# How to create webhook for telegram bot with heroku?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I am trying to deploy a simple echo2 bot using webhook. It's working fine with polling. But, I want to use the bot using webhook. I didn't find any easy to understand answer for this question on internet. 
What changes do I need to make in the below code to make the bot work using webhook..?

```
import logging

from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments update and
# context. Error handlers also receive the raised TelegramError object in error.
def start(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Hi!')


def help(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /help is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Help!')


def echo(update, context):
    """Echo the user message."""
    update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)


def error(update, context):
    """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)


def main():
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    # Make sure to set use_context=True to use the new context based callbacks
    # Post version 12 this will no longer be necessary
    updater = Updater("TOKEN", use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help))

    # on noncommand i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo))

    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the updater.start_polling() call and use this instead.

[Webhook for Heroku python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks#heroku)

Make sure you've already created your application on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Using the webhook:

```
# Use env variable PORT
PORT = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 3978)) 
updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0", port=PORT, url_path='TELEGRAM_TOKEN')

updater.bot.setWebhook('https://mywebhook/TELEGRAM_TOKEN')
```

Notes:

- set your TELEGRAM_TOKEN received by the BotFather
- set the relevant port (that might depend on the app running your webhook): the example above shows how to bind the port on Heroku
- webhook must listen on HTTPS

Comment: Hey..! Thanks for answering.

Comment: `updater.bot.setWebhook('https://rexxxxxxxxbot.herokuapp.com/1289991195:AAHWmkxxxxxxxxxxxxMZrIcBOl3Y')

updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0", port=8443, url_path='1289991195:xxxxxxxxxxxxZ5YTMZrIcBOl3Y')
updater.idle()`
This is what I have added to my code. I have also deleted updater.polling().
But still the bot is not working.
(I have just created a simple app on Heroku and copied the url to my code. I haven't changed any configuration.)

Comment: I have updated the answer: on Heroku you need to bind the port assigned to you dynamically (using the $PORT) 
PS avoid posting your real Telegram Token